How to adjust this circuit to allow measuring of negative voltage beside positive voltage through microcontroller?
I am using the following circuit to measure DC voltage that is up to 18V, and I was wondering if there's a way to make it able to measure negative DC voltage down to -18V as well:


What is the supply voltage connected to R168 and what is the ADC voltage range?

A very warm welcome to the site :-) On your schematics, never join 4 nets with a junction dot. Move the connections along so they're all T-junctions. Reason is schematics with small dots, or poor prints of schematics, can make it unclear if there's a dot there. So a '+'-junction may be two nets crossing over or really a 4-way junction. If you don't use 4-way junctions ever, the net connections are clear and unambiguous. It's a good policy, established long ago, and easy to do when drawing them. Thanks.

You can use an inverting op amp with a gain of <1.

The supply is 5V,

Thank you , I will in future Tony.

If the 18V is isolated from ADC supply you can shift the signal to Adc/2 using tl431.
(Working with Ac and Dc input signal also).

If not isolated, you can shift with DC blocking capacitor (if it is going about AC signal).
If input signal is DC you can shift with an op-amp.

Thank you very much, the power shares a common ground with the uC..

@Shamooooot Is the input signal Ac or Dc? What frequency range?

it is a DC signal..

Your circuit already can read -18 V to +18 V. With the component values shown, this gives you 0.249 V to 4.732 V at the input of the ADC.
You just need to do the appropriate math to convert the ADC voltage into the corresponding input voltage:
$$V_{in} = 8.03 (V_{ADC} - 2.49 V)$$

I actually tried, with -5V and -15V, I think the signal is getting clipped. The ADC reading for both of them stays the same.
Also when I connect the -15V I can see a small spark..

Then the diagram you gave us does not accurately represent the circuit you actually built.

The circuit is exactly what I have.. and I did a test again and here is the value to the ADC:
-5V = 2.06V
-15V = 2.06V
5V = 2.874
15V = 4.11
I think the current limit perhaps dropping the voltage on the -5V and -15V to around -1.7.. Even though I have it on 1A.
